# Timeout, asp.net c#, account - admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, timeout

I have admin page, i edit there my site, which work with sql. after 3-4 min the admin page logout and ask me again to enter the username and password. how can i change the minutes at the timeout ?

i have tried this at the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>
```

and this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="7200"/>
</authentication>
```

and...this:

```
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"

         executionTimeout="72000"
         appRequestQueueLimit="90000"
         shutdownTimeout="90000" />
```

and all the results are the same... after 3-4 min (even when i click there, not only when idle) - the system doin logout.

Comment: check if there is not any exception being occurred in your website, which destroys the session.

Comment: can you explain more detailed what you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was - to generate the keys at the machin key through iis 7 manager, and then change the session time again, at the iis 7 manager.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout in the 'forms' tag should work - do you have multiple configs?

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true"/>
        </authentication>
```

Add a sliding expiration - let me know if that solves your problem.  What browser are you using?  Could it be that your cookie is not being persisted?